Is there a more efficient way to generate all combinations of elements in an array?
Here is a recursive solution to generating all combinations of elements in an array.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Combinations {

    public static List<List<Integer>> generateCombinations(int[] arr) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<>();
        generate(arr, 0, current, result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void generate(int[] arr, int index, List<Integer> current, List<List<Integer>> result) {
        if (index == arr.length) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
            return;
        }

        current.add(arr[index]);
        generate(arr, index + 1, current, result);

        current.remove(current.size() - 1);
        generate(arr, index + 1, current, result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        List<List<Integer>> combs = generateCombinations(arr);
        System.out.println(combs);
    }    
}

Unfortunately, this solution is not fast enough for some problems I am solving. Is there a faster, more efficient way of generating all combinations of elements in an array?

If your code works, but you want to know how to improve it, it might be better suited for Code Review

By the way, did you mean "permutation"?  With permutations, order does matter. So, [1, 7] and [7, 1] are distinct. But, with combinations, order doesn't matter. So [1, 7] and [7, 1] would not both be in the results.

@OldDogProgrammer It doesn't select combinations of values in the array, but rather, combinations of indexes. This makes sense when you use [1 2 3 4 5] as the input array.

Combinations or permutations? Are [1, 2, 3] and [3, 2, 1] distinct or the same?

I don't know if this is faster, but I count down from 2^N and take the bits as reference.
Here's the complete runnable code.  I modified the createList code based on @user85421's comment.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Combinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5 };
        int maximum = (int) Math.round(Math.pow(2.0, arr.length));
//      System.out.println(maximum);
        
        int jndex = 1;
        for (int index = maximum - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            List<Integer> list = createList(arr, index);
            String s = String.format("%3d", jndex++);
            System.out.println(s + " " + list);
        }   
    }
    
    private static List<Integer> createList(int[] arr, int index) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String s = Integer.toBinaryString(index);
        int kndex = arr.length - 1;
        for (int jndex = s.length() - 1; jndex >= 0; jndex--) {
            char c = s.charAt(jndex);
            if (c == '1') {
                list.add(0, arr[kndex]);
            }
            kndex--;
        }
        return list;
    }
    
}


alternative: use a BigInteger and its testBit() method instead of int and toBinaryString()/charAt()

to be clear, using int limits the size of the array to 31 elements, 32 if handling negative numbers/overflow (63/64 if using long)

@user85421 If the OP really needs all the subsets that can be addressed by int or long, the program won't finish before the moon turns to dust and the sun will  turn into red giant.

@GyroGearloose maybe, but quoting from another comment: "depending on what you are doing with those subsets, you might not even have to generate them or iterate through all of them" :-|  (and still strange to convert an int to a binary string to test its bits - mainly regarding performance)

@GyroGearloose you must be kind of a pessimist - I tested posted code ¹ with an 31 long array (max for int), just removed/changed the printing to only print if the size of the subset is 2, it needed 245 seconds! The moon is still there, the sun also has not changed (just a bit nearer to the horizon) - sure, using long will need some more  time (~33K years) || ¹ but posted code does not work correctly: 1, 2, 4, 8, ... are all generating the same subset

@Gilbert - posted code is not considering the difference between strings like "1", "10", "100", ... and is generating the same subset for these; maybe its better to use bit operations to test bits, not only for performance

@user85421 "still strange to convert an int to a binary string" NO; NO, NO, not a string! Just use bit operations on the int, like "x&1" or "z = z << 1"

@user85421 "with an 31 long array " nah,I wasn't referring to the length of the array but to the length of the indexing variable. So, 31 bit turns out to $2^31$ possibilities.

@GyroGearloose what did you mean with "NO; NO, NO, not a string!" ?? YES; YESY, YES, - pPosted code IS using toBinaryString and that is not only strange, specially regarding performance, but also wrong!!

@Gyro: "nah,I wasn't referring to the length of the array but to the length of the indexing variable. So, 31 bit turns out to $2^31$ possibilities." what? did you understand the posted code? -- an array with 31 elements, that is, length 31, instead of the example array as in posted code, needs 31 bit for the indexing variable, and, in turn, as you wrote, 2^31 possibilities (see posted code:  Math.pow(2.0, arr.length)) -- printing all these may take forever, but creating those combinations (with testing/minimal printing to avoid code removal by JIT) toke 245 seconds (l~4 Minutes)

( and using long, we can estimate the needed time as being 245 sec * 2^32 - about 33400 years - still nothing compared to the five billion years¹ for the sun to start turning into a red star - most probably there will be no Java at that time, but many other  problems || ¹ End of the Sun )
